# Microservice communication to SOAP service

Tags: microservices

I am preparing Microservice design for one of the application where Microservice communicates to UI and that part is very straight forward and can achieve. Where other part is, one of microservice communicates to third party system using SOAP and it is SYNC communication. I want to avoid SYNC communication and build some components. That component should be responsible to fetch data from third party system and stores in local database.

So far I considered this could separate module and microservice communicates to internal module.

Now problem is

- Is there any possible solution where application achieve ASYNC communication. Although these are real time request
- Does it possible to store millions of transaction data in our database and then use database communication.